# The three colours surface filling in such a way...

Tags: geometry, logic

Is it possible to completely fill in square region 10 x 10 cm using 3 colours (for example red, blue and yellow) in such a way that you can not find 2 points in the same colour on exact 2 cm distance?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moser_spindle

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the centre $c$ of the region is red.  By considering two equilateral triangles sharing an edge, with $c$ at the other vertex of one triangle, show that
every point on the circle of radius $2 \sqrt{3}$ centred at $c$ would have to be red.  But that can't happen...

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very elegant solution :).

Comment: If I try to find minimal area (circle or square) where is still possible to paint surface in three colours than 2 x sqr(3) is critical dimension or not? Could you give a comment, pls?